# parse a specific column by its header in Java

Tags: java, parsing, csv, header

This is what my CSV file looks like :

```
 X, X2, Symbol, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume

 5, 9, AAPL, 01-Jan-2015, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 0
 2710, 289,  AAPL, 01-Jan-2015, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 0
 5415, 6500, AAPL, 02-Jan-2015, 111.39, 111.44, 107.35, 109.33, 53204600
```

How can I select values only from X and X2 columns? I've been trying with openCSV library but got nothing good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) can do this very easily and it's 2x faster than OpenCSV.

Here's how you can use it to select the columns of interest:

#### Input

```
    String input = "X, X2, Symbol, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume\n" +
            " 5, 9, AAPL, 01-Jan-2015, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 0\n" +
            " 2710, 289,  AAPL, 01-Jan-2015, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 0\n" +
            " 5415, 6500, AAPL, 02-Jan-2015, 111.39, 111.44, 107.35, 109.33, 53204600";
```

#### Configure

```
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //tells the parser to use the first row as the header row
    settings.selectFields("X", "X2"); //selects the fields
```

#### Parse

```
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new StringReader(input));
```

#### Print results

```
    for(String[] row : allRows){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
[5, 9]
[2710, 289]
[5415, 6500]
```

On the field selection, you can use any sequence of fields, and have rows with different column sizes, and the parser will handle this just fine.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same openCSV library feature: **CsvToBean**. 
You can create a bean class with attributes same as column names, then use this CSVtoBean to parse out the bean List as following.

Example from openCSV:

```
ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
strat.setType(YourOrderBean.class);
String[] columns = new String[] {"name", "orderNumber", "id"}; // the fields to bind do in your JavaBean
strat.setColumnMapping(columns);

CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();
List list = csv.parse(strat, yourReader);
```

*@src: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/*
,  *can check out the test cases for each of the available mapping strategies under the /test/java/com/opencsv/bean/* directory.